# akka - path to see the log message logged by akka.event.logging

Tags: akka

I am very new to Akka, and I have one question .. I am going through [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/logging.html) post.

can some one help me in understand where we could actually see the log messages?

> log.debug("Starting")
>
> log.error(reason, "Restarting due to [{}] when processing [{}]",
>         reason.getMessage, message.getOrElse(""))
>
> log.info("Received test")

will that come to any server path or somewhere, if we need to configure, where we should do? Pls, help me in understanding this.

Comment: if this is not an appropriate question. let me know - will remove instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation that you're referencing is obsolete. Here is the current link for logging in Akka: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html

Quoting the latter page:

> Logging in Akka is not tied to a specific logging backend. By default log messages are printed to STDOUT, but you can plug-in a SLF4J logger or your own logger.

If, for example, you want to use [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) to print the log messages to a file, add the following dependencies to your `build.sbt`:

```scala
val akkaVersion = "2.5.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  ...
)
```

And in `application.conf`:

```scala
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

Also, add a `logback.xml` configuration file to your application's `/src/main/resources` directory. For example:

```scala
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/path/to/myApp.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level %logger{36} %X{akkaSource} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

The location of the log file is in the above configuration. Look in the Logback documentation for more configuration options.

Comment: Great .. Thank you Jeff !!